# How to embed Salesforce merge field as clickable link for HTML button in Email template

Tags: email-template, html, button, url, merge-field

*Scenario-* When user registers through website(built with Django), his/her name, email address and activation link are temporarily stored in a custom object. The activation link is populated by Django and we are storing the same in a URL type field (**Activation_Field__c**) in Salesforce. An activation email should be sent to the user along with the activation link. I created a custom email template with HTML body.
*Issue:* I tried with **href="{!Custom_Object_Name__c.Activation_Field__c}"** in **button** tag still the button is not clickable[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKR2I.png)

**How can I insert the merge field to be clickable link for button tag in email template?**

P.S. I'm using Custom Email Template (without letterhead). So I don't have option of "insert link".

Edit- **I want the functionality of anchor tag with look and feel of button tag. How do I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks all for the inputs.

I implemented the HTML **anchor tag** and styled it with some CSS to look like a button. Though, the underline of anchor link still appears!

I'm still welcome for suggestions to implement the merge field as clickable button in button tag to be used in email template :)

Comment: You can remove the underline in anchor link by <a href= 'given any reference link' style='text-decoration:none';/>.Removes your underline.